# Using external train.txt on scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Hello i am so newbie at python and scikit learn

I am trying to make my model by using my train.txt.

my train txt is like the below.

```
pound NN I-NP
is VBZ B-VP
widely RB I-VP
expected VBN I-VP
to TO I-VP
take VB I-VP
```

when i try to load it with svm_load_files:

```
sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_files("path of the train.txt")
```

svm load gives me an error and complaining that my file is string and cannot convert to float.

Are there somebody can help me about importing my train.txt file into scikit and make my model by using features etc.

My main struggling is, i don't know how to use my train.txt on scikit-learn.Any help about this would be so cool

Any opinion will be appreciated thanks

Comment: It seems like file format you are using is not of svmlight. Have you gone through http://svmlight.joachims.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this library, but I am guessing your problem is with the file name. Have you tried a different name, like:

```
path_of_the_train.txt
```

The spaces may be causing the trouble. You could also trouble-shoot this by seeing if you can open the filename you are using with `open()`.

```
f = open('path of the train.txt', 'r')
print f
```

If that doesn't work, it should give you some more information about why.

Comment: nope, i get my file with no problem. The problem is my file is string text and should be converted to float for scikit i think